# How to ensure several parameters validation in a Zend_Rest_Controller?

Tags: zend-framework, validation, parameters, zend-rest

I need to make sure that several parameters are provided in my Zend_Rest_Controller.

Here is my code:

```
public function indexAction() {       
   $filters = array(
            'locid' => array('HtmlEntities', 'StringTrim')
            );

    $validators = array(
            'locid' => array('NotEmpty')
            );

    $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
    $input->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());


    if($input->isValid())
    {
        echo "Correct";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "missing/invalid params";
    }
}
```

But if I supply the url formated like this (without query string):

```
localhost/ws
```

it returns 'Correct', instead of 'missing/invalid params'.

Any easy solution or parameters to include in validators?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that behavior is correct. The servername: 'localhost' in your case must be provided to  call the actual validator

Comment: That behavior is correct, but what I want, is to force the query strings to be provided.